# Nginx proxy_pass 404 error, don't understand why

Tags: 404, nginx

I'm trying to pass off all calls to `/api` to my webservice but I keep getting 404s with the following config. Calls to `/` return `index.html` as expected. Does anyone know why?

```
   upstream backend{
server localhost:8080;
}

 server {

        location /api {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        }

        location / {

        root /html/dir;
        }

 }
```

More info here:

```
adept@HogWarts:/etc/nginx/sites-available$ curl -i localhost/api/authentication/check/user/email
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.2.1
Date: Mon, 22 Apr 2013 22:49:03 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive

adept@HogWarts:/etc/nginx/sites-available$ curl -i localhost:8080/authentication/check/user/email
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Mon, 22 Apr 2013 22:49:20 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{"user":["false"],"emailAddress":["false"]}
```

Comment: Is the 404 coming from nginx or from the backend?

Comment: My understanding is its coming form nginx, I put some more info in the question to help.

Comment: done chown -R on /html/dir?

Comment: No, but there is no problem with the  / location; calls to localhost return index.html from /html/dir as expected the problem is with the /api/ location

Comment: location /api { proxy_pass backend; } Needs to be this location /api/ { proxy_pass backend; }

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing a slash in your `proxy_pass`, see http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass.

It should be `proxy_pass http://backend/;`, if you want to map `/api` `location`from Nginx to `/` from upstream, otherwise, it'll be going to `/api` on upstream, too.